# How to use firebase-unity package?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

I am trying to use [firebase-unity](https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity) package and was confused :

How can I link my app to my firebase account. I can either do it as an iOS or Android app and for both I need iOS bundle id and other parameters which are missing in Unity.

Comment: what do you mean by "bundle id" is missing?

Comment: is this project working https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set your unity project `bundle identifier` in `Player Settings`
you can access it in
 `Edit -> project settings -> player settings`
[image]